# npm run build generates a static html with lots of error

Tags: next.js, static-site, static-site-generation, npm-build

So first things first im using the latest next js as of the moment and also the only package im using is headless ui, i also have one component file in components folder.

Now i tried making  "tabs" using headless ui , now i tried to export it following the documentation(up until the output:export part and npm run build ), however the generated html file contains lots of errors especially the 404.html (lol).

Now when i run the html file, it doesn't work as it is supposed to be unlike when i run it on npm run dev (also note that i made sure that there are no warnings and error in my code before exporting)

what should i do in this case?